# If Statement Condition Error In Javascript

Tags: javascript, if-statement, output

I am creating a website where you input when you were born and the code outputs your age in days. I achieve that by using "if" statements. I created a system for detecting invalid inputs. It detects the invalid inputs correctly but it also detects valid inputs as invalid. I'm hoping that someone can help me fix this. Here's the JS code.

```js
function ageInDays() {
  // variables
  var birthYear  = prompt("What Year Were You Born In?");
  var ageInDayss = (2021 - birthYear) * 365;

  //text
  if (birthYear > 1990 && birthYear < 2021) {
    var h1         = document.createElement('h1');
    var textAnswer = document.createTextNode("You are " + ageInDayss + " days old.");
    h1.setAttribute('id', 'ageInDays');
    h1.appendChild(textAnswer);
    document.getElementById('flex-box-result').appendChild(h1);
  }

  if (birthYear < 1920 || birthYear != 'NaN' || birthYear > 2021) {
    var h1         = document.createElement('h1');
    var textAnswer = document.createTextNode("Invalid Input. Please Try Again.");
    h1.setAttribute('id', 'ageInDays');
    h1.appendChild(textAnswer);
    document.getElementById('flex-box-result').appendChild(h1);
  }

  if (birthYear > 1920 && birthYear < 1990) {
    var h1         = document.createElement('span');
    var h2         = document.createElement('span');
    var textAnswer = document.createTextNode("You are " + ageInDayss + " days old.");
    var textAnswer1 = document.createTextNode(" Yikes... that's old.");
    h1.setAttribute('id', 'ageInDays');
    h2.setAttribute('id', 'yikes');
    h1.appendChild(textAnswer);
    h2.appendChild(textAnswer1);
    document.getElementById('flex-box-result').appendChild(h1).appendChild(h2);
  }
}
```

If you run this code, you can see that if you put a valid input (between 1920 and 2021), it detects the input as invalid. PLEASE help me fix this.

Comment: You probably want to add else ifs at each condition after the first one? Otherwise even if the first if condition is true, the rest of the code is still being executed

Comment: `if (birthYear<1920 || birthYear!= 'NaN' || birthYear>2021)` - the value of `birthYear` would almost never be `'NaN'`, so this condition would almost always be true.

Comment: FYI, you've neglected to account for people born on 1920,1990, and 2021 because the > and < operators are not inclusive.... also, leap years

Comment: yeah ik that. I'll do that later when the output system works.

Comment: I made a [js fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/psw1mvg9/) for you.  There's no problem with the input, as you can see.  It has to do with how you display it.

Comment: There's a problem with the output. There's a mistake somewhere

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/s2Lx10a3/1/   I edited it.  Try again.  It should just output to an alert box.  I commented out the rest since I don't have your html

Comment: The output works but if you put letters into the input box, you don't get the invalid output message.  https://jsfiddle.net/7zfaj2Le/2/

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/240027/discussion-between-muhammad-ali-and-exceptional-exception).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

wrap it in an 'if' to validate the input first

```
 // Age In Days
function ageInDays() {
    // variables
    var birthYear = prompt("What Year Were You Born In?");
    //var ageInDayss = (2021 - birthYear) * 365;
    const bDate  = new Date(birthYear + "-01-01");
    const today = new Date();
    const diffTime = Math.abs(bDate - today);
        const ageInDays = Math.ceil(diffTime / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)); 
    // variable css

    //text
if (isNaN(birthYear) == false) {

    
    if (birthYear=>1990 && birthYear<=2021) {
        var h1 = document.createElement('h1');
        var textAnswer = document.createTextNode("You are " + ageInDays + " days old.");
        h1.setAttribute('id', 'ageInDays');
        h1.appendChild(textAnswer);
        document.getElementById('flex-box-result').appendChild(h1);

    } 


    if (birthYear<1990) {
        var h1 = document.createElement('span');
        var h2 = document.createElement('span');
        var textAnswer = document.createTextNode("You are " + ageInDays + " days old.");
        var textAnswer1 = document.createTextNode(" Yikes... that's old.");
        h1.setAttribute('id', 'ageInDays');
        h2.setAttribute('id', 'yikes');
        h1.appendChild(textAnswer);
        h2.appendChild(textAnswer1);
        document.getElementById('flex-box-result').appendChild(h1).appendChild(h2);
    }

 }else{
                var h1 = document.createElement('h1');
        var textAnswer = document.createTextNode("Invalid Input. Please Try Again.");
        h1.setAttribute('id', 'ageInDays');
        h1.appendChild(textAnswer);
        document.getElementById('flex-box-result').appendChild(h1);
 }
}
```

Comment: no problem.  FYI, I made an edit to account for the current date, assuming the person's birthday is Jan 1st.  see the fiddle here :https://jsfiddle.net/xjyrd51f/2/

Answer (score 1):

Well, your code does what you told it to do. You are checking if the birthyear isn't nan and obviously it isn't. Your if statement should be like this.

```js
if (birthYear < 1990 || birthYear > 2021 || birthYear == "NaN")
```

Comment: I changed it, it's working for the most part. When I input in a "string", it doesn't output anything.

Comment: To fix this you just need to put this piece of code at the beginning of the function birthYear = parseInt(birthYear)

Comment: I put it but it still didn't fix the problem. I made a js fiddle so you can help me understand a bit more. Here's the link: https://jsfiddle.net/7zfaj2Le/2/

Comment: From what I can see it works.

Comment: The output works but if you put letters into the input box, you don't get the invalid output message.

Comment: here: https://jsfiddle.net/yemsa319/